# CSS Style For Div element Using Attribute

Tags: css

```
<div class="td" disabled="disabled">PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP</div>
```

How to Write Css style for this type of DIV element using the attribute disabled

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector [`[attr=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
.td[disabled=disabled] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="td" disabled="disabled">PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select your div by using its `disabled` attribute. Here is the the CSS code which select that `div` by its attribute.

CSS Code-

```
div[disabled="disabled"]{
  color:white;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Don't just post _Try this CSS code_, explain what you did and/or why

Comment: @LGSon Thank you for pointing me this, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```css
.td[disabled="disabled"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="td" disabled="disabled">PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP</div>
```

```
 }
```